# Cakephp 3.0 modify "add" Bake template

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am creating a new Theme within CakePHP to bake a couple of database tables. I have been able to run the bake command and also I have modified the index.ctp template file.
Now, I want to change the add template. The default "add" page shows a sidebar with some quick links to related tables and a form on the right column. I want to remove the links, change the styles and add some other stuff. However when I open the default add.ctp this is what I see:

```
echo $this->element('form');
```

And that's all.

How can I modify the elements of this page if that's the only available code?
Is there any other file I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `Bake Theme` where you place your `form.ctp` file, you can copy the one from the Bake plugin and modify as you like:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html#creating-a-bake-theme

Then you can run the bake command with your own theme:

bin/cake bake view Posts add --theme jpruizs

About the `$this->element('form')` thing. It is a View element:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements

So you just need to got to the `Element` folder inside the plugin `Template` folder and see what it does :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don´t have to create an extra theme. Just follow these instructions and add the form.ctp to app/src/Template/Bake/Element

Works like a charm. I tried it over the Plugin too, but did not work and why make it complicated if it´s easy (if you want to change the outcome for all the forms)

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html#customizing-the-bake-templates